# TabControl с уровнями вложенности

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Как сделать пункты (табы) в TabControl, чтобы они могли иметь уровни вложенности, как в TreeView?

```
Пункт 1
Пункт 2
...Пункт 2.1
...Пункт 2.2
Пункт 3
...Пункт 3.1
......Пункт 3.1.1
```

Comment: легко - табконтрол в табконтроле в табконтроле, `HierarchicalDataTemplate` вас спасет

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Можно рассмотреть вариант с treeView, где при нажатии на узел будет присваиваться соответствующий шаблон контентной области.
Если сможете решить проблему через tabControl тоже бы ознакомился! Ранее сталкивался с подобного рода проблемой, очень интересно будет посмотреть на реализацию через tabControl, в частности на то как будут группироваться tabItem